# change colour of highest total column value in rdl report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

[image: how to highlighte highest number of a total column]

In rdl report i am showing total column as sum aggregation, i want to highlighte highest of that total.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the report design, I'm assuming this is a matrix but cannot be sure.

Comment: Above image is just a replica in excel. and it is what i want to see at the end. currently struggling to set font colour as red for highest value in total column.Total column is sum(aa,bb... ll)

Comment: You'll still need to show more info, what does your data look like in the database? This will make a difference to how you build the report and therefore how the problem is solved. I' will post a generic example later but any info you provide will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a generic answer that makes lots of assumptions. As you question does not contain enough info for a definitive answer but hopefully this will give you enough that you resolve your problem.

To recreate this do the following (and then adapt to suit your specific situation)

Create a new report.

Add a datset and use the following query as the dataset query

```
-- create some sample data
DECLARE @t TABLE(Customer varchar(10), Product varchar(10), Quantity int)
INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
('Dave', 'Hammer', 6), ('Dave', 'Saw', 6),('Dave', 'Hammer', 1),
('George', 'Drill', 3),('George', 'Hammer', 6),('George', 'Saw', 6),('George', 'Hammer', 1),
('Mary', 'Drill', 3),('Mary', 'Hammer', 6),
('Jane', 'Saw', 6),('Jane', 'Hammer', 1),('Jane', 'Drill', 3)

-- return the sample data plus a total per customer
SELECT *
        , CustomerTotal = SUM(Quantity) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer)
    FROM @t
```

This give use the following results

[image]

Next add a Matrix control to the report. 
Drag the fields to the matrix as shown here 
[image]

Customer to "Rows"; Product to "Columns"; Quantity to "Data"

You should now have a matrix  with some row and column groups shown underneath.
next we need to add a total column so right-click the "Product" column group select "Add Total => After"

[image]

Finally, we need to test if the value in the total column matches the largest `CustomerTotal` in our dataset. If it does match then change the textbox `color` property to "Red".

We can use this expression in the textbox `color` to do this..

```
=IIF(
    Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value) = MAX(Fields!CustomerTotal.Value, "DataSet1"), 
    "Red",
    "Black")
```

What this does is take the total quantity in the current scope (the entire row) and compare it to the highest CustomerTotal with the scope "Dataset1" which is the entire dataset. If the two match, set the vlue to "Red", else set it to "Black"

With a bit of a tidy-up the final output looks like this.

[image]

Comment: what if i am am not getting CustomerTotal column? my scenario i dont have any such column which has total count

Comment: If you look at the dataset query you can see how to add this at that point. If this does not help, add more info, show us what your data looks like.